# UTF-8 Connection to odbc SQL 2000 database

Tags: php, sql, utf-8, character-encoding, odbc

currently I have a problem displaying chinese characters on a website. These characters are stored in a Windows SQL 2000 Database, which I acces with PHP ODBC functions. Even when I set the `CHARSET=utf-8` in the dns of the connection.

Usind MYSQL database I simply send a query like

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=utf8
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8
```

Is there a simmilar possibility to do so with ODBC database?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230971/inserting-unicode-characters-with-php-odbc-ms-sql

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ryan! :) But actually the utf8_decode does not work for me. :(

Comment: I found the solution, the string has to be encoded by mb_convert_encoding(). It was in GB2312.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the string has to be encoded by mb_convert_encoding(). It was in GB2312.