# Character Set issue using SQL Server and ODBC in php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, dsn

I connected to to `sqlsever2008` with `odbc(with dsn) and php` but problem is that when I retrieve information from that it has character like `���������`. My  datatype in `sqlserver` is `nvarchar`. Any idea why it is happening?

NOTE: The page is `utf8`.

```
Edit:
```

I use `echo utf8_encode(odbc_result($this->result,'name') );` and characters are like:

```
ÂãæÒÔ ÒÈÇäÂãæÒ
```

i retrieve information like this:

odbc_result($this->result,'name')

Comment: how to retrieve data? put sample code please

Comment: have you checked if you had a `BOM` issue? I always check that too.

Comment: @Fred please explain more.

Comment: what is your sql statement i mean.also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750244/php-odbc-encoding-problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230971/inserting-unicode-characters-with-php-odbc-ms-sql

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine Consult this link for details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem.

```
iconv("Windows-1256", "UTF-8", "$temp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `utf8_decode()` or `utf8_encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the code page your sql server has been installed is different with your native language. perhaps you need to reinstall the sql server with correct code page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the locale with:

```
Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative -> Change system locate
```

Comment: Help them, help me or help you? A little nitpicking, sorry. I ask because I try to determine whether you are trying to answer or saying thanks.

Comment: I assumed this is a proposed answer. Please double check that the edit is correct.